# Set characteristic notification on Mac BLE Central for an Android(6.0) BLE peripheral characteristics fails

Tags: android, ios, macos

## Problem:

I got Mac book (OS X 10.11.6) acts as BLE Central device and Android Phone (Os 6.0) acts as Peripheral device.

**Android Peripheral** advertises **characteristic-1** with properties BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY

**Mac book(BLE Central)** discovers Android Peripheral successfully with **characteristic-1**.
However, when BLE Central tries to do **setNotifyValue:YES** for this characteristic fails with below error.

***Error changing notification state:Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=0 "Unknown error." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown error.}***

Incase, if the ***Peripheral device is an iPhone(iOS)*** which has similar characteristic then **setNotifyValue:YES** gets succeeded.

I tried the below combinations for the **characteristic-1** with

**1-**
BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_INDICATE

**2-**
BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY

**3-**
BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_INDICATE

But unfortunately none of them worked.

Can some one help me in setting notifiable to YES on Mac OS X Central for Android Peripheral characteristic ?

Answer (score 0):

On android, you need set descriptor to enable notification.

```
    BluetoothGattService gattService = new BluetoothGattService(YOUR_SERVICE_UUID,
            BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);

    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(YOUR_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_INDICATE, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE);
    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = new BluetoothGattDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"),
            BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_READ | BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_WRITE);
    descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
    characteristic.addDescriptor(descriptor);

    gattService.addCharacteristic(characteristic);
```

Comment: NO. This doesn't work. I tried the above method. Here is the error on MAC side BLE Scanner:                                                                        `Error changing notification state:Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=1 "One or more parameters were invalid." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=One or more parameters were invalid.}`

Comment: Make sure you are using "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" as descriptor UUID. It works for me.

Comment: OK. Why can't we use the UUID other than the one mentioned above?

Comment: So it works now? Based on BLE spec, that UUID is for subscription.

Comment: Error is no more appearing. However, If I write some message to this characteristics then it is not reached on to MAC Side scanner. Do I need to write to Descriptor rather to the Characteristic itself