# Central does not notify when peripheral characteristic value changed

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, chat, notify

I am developing BLE Chat Application, Chat from MAC->iOS and iOS->MAC is Done. I have made MAC to act like Central and iOS act like Peripheral. From Central to Peripheral i use write characteristics to write value to peripherals. But for data transfer from peripheral to central i use below function.
peripheralManager.updateValue(data, for: readCharacteristics, onSubscribedCentrals: nil)

It automatically calls delegate at central side named didUpdateValueFor Characteristics and its works fine for me.

Now the is issue just on Android side when i use the same code on Android instead of using iOS, there is not any function named peripheralManager.updateValue in android but when i use setValue function to update value of characteristic it does not notify to central.

What is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. I have just changed my Characteristics settings from Notifications to indications and change the descriptor UUID. Now BLE Chat working fine.
For more information i want to share a link which helps me a lot.

[Set characteristic notification on Mac BLE Central for an Android(6.0) BLE peripheral characteristics fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39145760/set-characteristic-notification-on-mac-ble-central-for-an-android6-0-ble-perip)